# Pip Install Proxy Connection Issues

Tags: networking, python, cmd.exe, proxy, http

System details: Windows11, cmd.exe

Hey there!

I am facing an issue linked to pip package installation for python. I had no proxy set before the last week and I was using the command `pip install package_name` to install packages for python. No probs at all.

Then, I had set a proxy username and password for my institute. After that, I tried using `pip install` to install packages, but it is failing every time.

Below is the output for installing `pygal`. With other packages, the same problem persists.

`WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000025CCEB57DD0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))': /simple/pygal/`

I tried resetting the proxy to get it work. With `netsh winhttp` and also `set http_proxy`, I reset the proxy and connected to the internet directly without any proxy. Still, `pip install` is not working.

Any leads? A gazillion thanks in advance.

Trial 1:

`netsh winhttp reset proxy`

Trial 2:

`setx http_proxy=''`

and with `echo %http_proxy%`, the output is `''`. That means, the proxy has been reset to default.

Trial 3:

`py -m pip config list`

With my home network and no proxy, I still can't have access to `pip install`.